# How can I put my gt-s5660 functionaly again?

Tags: root-access, rom, samsung-galaxy-gio

I have my galaxy gio rooted with superuser (it was vodafone), and I downloaded the px-cwm-v2.zip, and used rom manager app with no changes from me.
Now my phone gets stuck in Galaxy Gio Model apresentation, the second image, and I have no back up.

What are the possible solutions to resolve this?

Comment: Check [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575), get a fitting ROM, flash it. Depending on whether you still can boot to recovery or download mode / fastboot, that is. If you can boot to recovery, you could also try a Dalvik cache wipe or factory reset, in case just something got stuck.